# PHP interactive shell, auto echo and a new line

Tags: php, interactive-shell

Greetings fellow programmers!

Is there a way to get PHPs interactive shell, `php -a`, to behave more like Rails console or the console in Chrome? I have looked through the flags for the php-command, but no dice.

**What I get:**

```
php > $a = 0;
php > $a;
php > echo $a;
0php >
```

**What I want**

```
php > $a = 0;
0
php > $a;
0
php > echo $a;
0
php >
```

Comment: There's [Facebook's `phpsh`](https://github.com/facebook/phpsh), but it looks like their original fork isn't maintained anymore. It worked a while ago.

Comment: You're asking for broken functionality. It behaves exactly as it should, however if you want a newline - why not add it yourself? It's really not hard to use `printf("\n%s", $a);` instead of `echo $a;` to accommodate for CLI usage.

Comment: Maybe you see it as broken but I would see it as a feature. The point (to what I understand) the interactive shell is about easy access to php, for testing or something similar. Trying out your class or something. It would be a hell of a lot more convenient and easy to use if it behaved as I proposed.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least three possibilities to solve this problem:

1. Manually add `PHP_EOL` to all your `echo`: `echo $a . PHP_EOL`;
2. Introduce your idea on official [php ideas wiki](https://wiki.php.net/ideas#ideas_introduction) and wait until someone implement it.
3. Learn [php git workflow for external contributors](https://wiki.php.net/vcs/gitworkflow#workflow_for_external_contributors), create needed functionality and send the patch to developers.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2022, [PsySH](https://psysh.org/) seems to be a modern maintained valid solution for the asked question:

```
Psy Shell v0.11.5 (PHP 7.4.3 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> $a = 0
=> 0

>>> $a
=> 0

>>> echo $a
0⏎
```

All the more:

- as one can see above, semi-colon is optional
- the output is slightly different for an `echo` expression
- a single `eval` statement dropped anywhere in a code base is enough to set a breakpoint powered by this REPL

Answer (score 0):

Check into [Boris](https://github.com/d11wtq/boris), described as "PHP's missing [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop)".  `echo` and `print` still require manual newlines, but naked expressions are evaluated and pretty-printed:

```
[1] boris> $a = 0;
// 0
[2] boris> $a;
// 0
[3] boris> echo $a;
0[4] boris>
```